# running two services in Azure

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have created a WCF file which I am running a REST services in that outputs the XML, this data is connected to my my WP8 where the user can input data, and then call the data back in a a list view.

I have on a separate project a push notification service which i want to add, to link with the mobile phone, but also run on the same server as the REST service.

Aim: To integrate the push notification into the application.

I have been looking around and if someone could possible clear it up, as in my REST WCF I added a new item in which is a WCF service, but when i try adding a service reference it doesn't come up and my cloud.... service1 and 2 comes up an error. I then tried to put the code inside the REST WCF and this also did not work.

Can anyone suggest the best method to do this?

```
namespace WCFServiceWebRole1
{

[ServiceContract]

public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]

    void Subscribe(string deviceid, string uri);

    [OperationContract]

    void SendToast(string title, string message);

    [OperationContract]

    void SendTile(string title, string count);

}

}

 namespace WCFServiceWebRole1
{

public class Service1 : IService1
{

    private static Uri uri;

    private static String device_ID;



    // Save the subscription channel with the phone's deviceID to persistant storage

    public void Subscribe(string deviceid, string subscriberUri)
    {

        uri = new Uri(subscriberUri);

        device_ID = deviceid;


    }


    // Send toast notification method

    public void SendToast(string title, string message)
    {

        // build our xml payload as a string

        string toastMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +

            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +

                "<wp:Toast>" +

                    "<wp:Text1>" + title + "</wp:Text1>" +

                "<wp:Text2>" + message + "</wp:Text2>" +

                "</wp:Toast>" +

            "</wp:Notification>";

        // set notification type to 'toast'

        String messageType = "toast";



        SendMessage(uri, toastMessage, messageType, "2");

    }

    // Send tile notification method

    public void SendTile(string title, string count)
    {

        string tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +

                            "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +

                                "<wp:Tile>" +

                                    "<wp:Count>" + count + "</wp:Count>" +

                                    "<wp:Title>" + title + "</wp:Title>" +

                                "</wp:Tile> " +

                                "</wp:Notification>";

        // set notification type to 'token' for tile

        String messageType = "token";



        SendMessage(uri, tileMessage, messageType, "1");

    }

    private static void SendMessage(Uri uri, String message, String messageType, String 
    notificationClass)
    {

        HttpWebRequest sendNotificationRequest =               
       (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";

        sendNotificationRequest.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();

        sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";

        sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", notificationClass);

        sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", messageType);

        byte[] strBytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(message);

        sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = strBytes.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {

            requestStream.Write(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);

        }



        try
        {

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();

            var notiticationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];

            var notitificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];

            var deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.Write(ex.ToString());

            // Ignoring the response.

            // In a production application you should review the response and

            // code appropriate for the specific response.

            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941100%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

        }

    }




}
```

REST

```
  namespace WCFServiceWebRole1
{



public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public bool addProfile(string guid, string firstname, string surname)
    {

        // code to add a new user profile to SQL database



        // parse guid string to proper guid type

        Guid guid_new = Guid.Parse(guid);

        // creates a new instance of our database objects (user table in this case)

        using (var context = new sad_Rest_serviceEntities())
        {

            // add a new object (or row) to our user profile table

            context.user_profile.Add(new user_profile()

           // bind each database column to the parameters we pass in our method

           // guid, firstname, surname, and email

            {

                guid = guid_new,

                firstname = firstname,

                surname = surname

            });

            // commit changes to the user profile table

            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;

        }

    }

    public Users[] viewProfilesXML(string guid)
    {

        // get the connections string stored in the web.config file as a string

        string connectionString =    
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        // create  new sql connections using the connection string

        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        // create a new sql command called getUsers

        SqlCommand getUsers = thisConnection.CreateCommand();

        // create a temp list to store the rows of users returned from the database

        List<Users> users = new List<Users>();

        // open the sql connection and construct the select query

        thisConnection.Open();

        string sql = "select * from user_profile where guid=@guid";

        // paramertise your query to stop sql injections!

        getUsers.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", guid);

        getUsers.CommandText = sql;

        // create an sql data adapter using the getUsers query

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(getUsers);



        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds, "user_profile");

        // for every row returned call our DataContract in IService1.cs

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["user_profile"].Rows)
        {

            users.Add(new Users()

            {

                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),

                Guid = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),

                Firstname = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),

                Surname = Convert.ToString(dr[3])

            });

        }

        //Return data for XML output

        thisConnection.Close();

        return users.ToArray();

    }       
}


 namespace WCFServiceWebRole1
 {


[ServiceContract]

public interface IService1
{




    [OperationContract]

    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,

    UriTemplate = "users?guid={guid}&firstname={firstname}&surname={surname}")]

    bool addProfile(string guid, string firstname, string surname);




    [OperationContract]

    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",

     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,

     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,

    UriTemplate = "viewusers?format=xml&guid={guid}")]

    Users[] viewProfilesXML(string guid);
}

    [DataContract]
    public class Users
    {

        [DataMember]

        private int id;

        public int Id
        {

            get { return id; }

            set { id = value; }

        }

        [DataMember]

        private string guid;

        public string Guid
        {

            get { return guid; }

            set { guid = value; }

        }

        [DataMember]

        private string firstname;

        public string Firstname
        {

            get { return firstname; }

            set { firstname = value; }

        }

        [DataMember]

        private string surname;

        public string Surname
        {

            get { return surname; }

            set { surname = value; }

        }


}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you really expect many people to read all that code? Can't you narrow down your problem, then post only the code that matters to the problem?

Comment: They don't have to read it, was just demonstrating what i have, the question is in the main body.

Comment: If you don't feel the readers need to read all of your code, then don't _post_ all of  your code. Don't waste our time with code that is not relevant to the problem. There are many users who need help, and not nearly as many users who help them. Please don't suck up our time.